# How to copy a rectangle inside a canvas to a bitmap?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How does one copy a rectangle from inside a FireMonkey `TCanvas` to a `TBitmap` (or other `TCanvas`)?

`CopyRect` is not available in FMX.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution can be this:

```
var
NewBitmap:TBitmap;

NewBitmap:=Rectangle1.MakeScreenshot;
```

Comment: That would be easy if I were handed a TControl, like a TRectangle. But sadly the procedure is only handed a TCanvas.

Comment: @Domus, tControl.MakeScreenshot() uses tControl.PaintTo() - so see how .paintTo() method handles painting from a tCanvas to a tCanvas

Comment: @iPath Certainly not straightforward. First look at that procedure didn't really give many hints, so it's a bit of a time investment.

Comment: @iPath: I only tested with XE2 (update 4), but if I **directly** draw something on a TRectangle, this is visible as long as the Rectangle is visible... if I minimize my app or cover it with another app... my canvas modifications are lost... BTW, if I call a MakeScreenshot, I have my Rectangle control as it has been designed, without my canvas updates... so I think, you need to _save_ all your updates and replay them after each repaint...